# how to create relationship between three table in laravel?

Tags: laravel

i have three table:

***Suppliers***

```
id | name | type

1  | Test1 | Seller

2 | Test2 | Manufacturer
```

***Products***

```
id | name

1 | product1

2 | product2
```

***Prices***

```
id | supplier_id | product_id | price

1 | 1 | 1 | 1000

2| 2 | 1 | 2000
```

each supplier have many products and each products belong to many suppliers. 
Now each supplier can have a separate price for each product.

i have a question that how to create model and table for this scenario?

Comment: you want the tables and models for the Price table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have two tables with models:

```
Product and Supplier
```

Within /Database/Migrations create_products table:

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

create_suppliers table:

```
Schema::create('suppliers', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('type');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

You will need a pivot table, so create it with Artisan command:

```
php artisan make:migration create_product_supplier_table
```

*A quick note: Pivot names should be in alphabetical order to fit laravel name convention. 'P' letter comes first and then 'S' (product_supplier) in this case.*

product_supplier table:

```
Schema::create('product_supplier', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('supplier_id');
    $table->integer('price');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Now, you will need the following relation declarations in two models

Within App\Product class:

```
protected $guarded = [];

public function suppliers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Supplier::class)->withPivot('price');
}
```

And also in App\Supplier class:

```
protected $guarded = [];

public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withPivot('price');
}
```

You set it up now. Let's give it a try:

```
$supplier = App\Supplier::create(['name' => 'supplier1', 'type' => 'seller']);
$product = App\Product::create(['name' => 'product1']);

$supplier->products()->attach($product, ['price' => 80]);
```

Call it back:

```
$supplier->products; // it will give you the products that attached to supplier.
```

So, the any supplier can have any product with any price tag.